# Identify wordpress theme code to modify it

Tags: wordpress-theming

I use a free theme with a parent theme and a child theme.
In WP admin, "Main page settings" allows me to activate / desactivate theme's sections.

I would like to customize a section but I don't know which .php file it corresponds to.

By inspecting the HTML code of the home page with this section enabled, I see that the html refers to the class <section id "about_section" ....>.

A search on the content in the template files shows me 3 affected files:

```
wp-content\themes\tour-operator\functions.php
wp-content\themes\travel-agency\inc\extras.php
wp-content\themes\travel-agency\inc\js\customize.js
```

I found this function:

```
 `travel_agency_get_homepage_section () 
{
$ sections = array (); ... 
$ ed_about = get_theme_mod ('ed_about_section', true); ... 
// Sections from travel agency companion 
if ($ ed_about) array_push ($ sections, 'about');`
```

But I don't know what to do with it to find the file to modify.
Thanks for your great help!
Theo.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but maybe [What The File](https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/) can help out.

Comment: Thanks. I have an other plugin installed which do the same thing but it didnt help me....

Comment: theme/<theme_name>front-page.php file wich is a generic file